# Keeping Javascript in Scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

I have a web app which loads a set of data with ajax, that data launches a lightbox, when the lightbox closes I need to refresh the original data by recalling the initial ajax.  I am hitting some issues keeping the javascript in scope.

**index.php** has some ajax in it to draw the list of child pages:

```
<!-- Container for the content  -->
<div id="pageListContainer" data-category-id="1"></div>

<script>

// Re-usable function to draw the pages
function drawPageList() {
    var container = '#pageListContainer';
    var categoryId = $(container).data('categoryId');
    $.post('webservice.php', {action: 'drawPageList', categoryId: categoryId}, function(data) {
        $(container).removeClass('loading').html(data);
    });
}

// Now draw the pages
drawPageList();

// Function to open the page links as an iFrame in a lightbox
$('#pageList a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.fancybox({
        type : 'iframe',
        padding : 0,
        autoSize: false,
        width: 440,
        height: 440,
        href: this.href + "&lightbox=true",
    });
});

</script>
```

**webservice.php** will return something like this:

```
<ul id="pageList">
    <li><a href="page.php?pageId=1">Page One</a></li>
    <li><a href="page.php?pageId=2">Page Two</a></li>
<ul>
```

The above fails because the lightbox open function targets "#pageList a" and that part of the DOM is loaded via ajax.  To solve this I can add the $('#pageList a').click() function to the ajax result from webservice.php, but then I'm segmenting my JS into multiple places and I get other scope issues.  Is there a best practice for global scope of JS functions like this?

Comment: i think `var categoryId = $(container).data('categoryId');` this should be `var categoryId = $(container).data('category-id');`

Comment: @DipeshParmar Depends on the version of jQuery. With 1.6 or later, both strings refer to the same `data-` attribute: http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5; for 1.4.3 through 1.5.x, you're correct; and, prior to that, you have to use `.attr()`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski thanx you so much clearing me..thats why i said I THINK...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use event delegation. This lets you attach the event handler to a parent element that remains in the DOM instead of being dynamically loaded. For example:

```
$('#pageListContainer').on( 'click', '#pageList a', function( event ) {
    // ...
});
```

Instead of attempting to attach an event handler to the `'#pagelist a'` elements, this attaches it to the `'#pageListContainer'` parent element.

Comment: That's great thanks, I can now load the ligthbox from the ajax-generated links which is perfect. The second step is that inside the lightbox I'd like to be able to call the original drawPageList() function (to refresh the view once changes are made). I tried simply using parent.drawPageList() but it gave an "Object has no method" error. Is there a similar workaround for this scenario?

Comment: I can't tell from that description where the error is. Is it failing to call `drawPageList()` in the parent page? Or is it getting into that function but something in it isn't working? If it's making it into the function, jQuery could be using the wrong document context. But hard to say without being able to run it and look in the debugger. Have you tried putting a `debugger;` statement in `drawPageList()` and seeing if it gets there, then stepping through the function? Also can you put up a test page on jsfiddle.net or wherever you like?